# Sum up values in SQL once all values are available

Tags: mysql, sql

I have events flowing into a MySQL database and I need to group and sum the events to transactions and store away into another table.  The data looks like:

```
+----+---------+------+-------+
| id | transid | code | value |
+----+---------+------+-------+
|  1 |       1 | b    |    12 |
|  2 |       1 | i    |    23 |
|  3 |       2 | b    |    34 |
|  4 |       1 | e    |    45 |
|  5 |       3 | b    |    56 |
|  6 |       2 | i    |    67 |
|  7 |       2 | e    |    78 |
|  8 |       3 | i    |    89 |
|  9 |       3 | i    |    90 |
+----+---------+------+-------+
```

The events arrive in batches and I would like to create the transaction by summing up the values for each transid, like:

```
select transid, sum(value) from eventtable group by transid;
```

but only after all the events for that transid have arrived. That is determined by the event with the code e (b for the beginning, e for the end and i for varying amount of intermediates).  Being a novice in SQL, how could I implement the requirement for the existance of the end code before the summing?

Comment: did you try using triggers, they could solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps with `having`:

```
select transid, sum(value)
from eventtable 
group by transid 
having max(case code when 'e' then 1 end)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select transid, sum(value) from eventtable 
group by transid 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

you should count the records in the group. So when there is (b)egin, (i)?? don't know what it is and (e)nd this group is not filtered out.

Comment: I think there can be more than 1 'i': "varying amount of intermediates"

Comment: Ouch.. Yes. Didn't notice that there could be several i